# Convert a string into an array

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I have the following string:

```
key:surname +++ value:Tesla|||key:name +++ value:Nikola|||key:age +++ value:86|||
```

How with the PHP I can convert it into an associative array? Like:

```
echo $arr['surname'];
Tesla
```

I'm trying it, but can't write a correct expression:

```
$str= "key:surname +++ value:Tesla|||key:name +++ value:Nikola|||key:age +++ value:86|||"; 
preg_match_all("regex_here",$str,$out); 
unset($out[0]); 
$out = array_combine($out[1],$out[2]) ; 
print_r($out);
```

Thanks.

Comment: If this is your design of an information storage system, I would suggest you look at json (specifically `json_encode` and `json_decode`) as an easier, better designed system.

Comment: Just a note: you're aware of PHP's `serialize` and `unserialize` functions? See: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: What were your tries regarding the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
$str= "key:surname +++ value:Tesla|||key:name +++ value:Nikola|||key:age +++ value:86|||"; 
preg_match_all("/key:(.*?) \+\+\+ value:(.*?)\|\|\|/", $str, $out);
$out = array_combine($out[1], $out[2]) ; 
print_r($out);
```

As mentioned by others, though, if you're the one storing the data like that, there are many better ways to store the data, including serializing and JSON, which you might want to look into.

Comment: This doesn't work. It only returns the last match. The `array_combine` is wrong. Otherwise, a decent solution.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
preg_match_all("/:(\w+).*?:(\w+)/", $str, $matches);
var_dump(array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]));
```

Answer (score 0):

why there has three + and three | . If it's you make it that. I think you could change it to one. Then the explode function can help you !